# Multi GPU CNN performance way better than single GPU

Tags: natural-language, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I'm training a CNN for text classification using tensorflow. When I train the model using multiple GPUs per the [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html), the performance on the dev set goes up 5%!

In the multi GPU case, the batch is split up into n smaller batches which are trained on n models (with identical parameters) on each GPU. The gradients of each submodel are then averaged to produce the gradients used to update the model parameters before the next iteration.

Is there any reason to believe that the multi-GPU procedure might produce better results than a single GPU case or is a bug a more likely explanation?

Comment: Have you noticed this +5% improvement on more than one run, and how do you select the epoch for which you report the result on the development set?

Comment: I see it on every run that I do. I eyeball the epoch, letting it run in both cases until the dev seems to have peaked and the model looks like it's overfitting.